# Convert IList<T> to BindingList<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting, bindinglist

How can I cast an `IList<Customer>` list to `BindingList<Customer>`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
var yourList = new List<Customer>();
var listBinding = new BindingList<Customer>(yourList);
```

[BindingList Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132681.aspx)

You don't need to do a cast, just provide the `BindingList<T>` class constructor with `IList<T>`, which you have.

Comment: Since there is no ToBindingList() method with LINQ, can you answer the question for those cases? something like this:     BindingList<cRecord> cr = cRecords.Take(TotalDays).ToList();