# Convert generic list to BindingList<T>

Tags: c#, winforms, generic-list, bindinglist

I have BindingList object which is attched with DataGridView.

```
BindingList<FilesToProcessDataModels> Listfiles = new BindingList<FilesToProcessDataModels>();
dataGridFiles.DataSource = Listfiles;
```

I want to filter items list by given condition in Where. like following:

```
dataGridSheets.DataSource = Listfiles.Where(i => i.Status == FileStatus.NotProcessed).ToList();
```

Above code is working fine but I want to assign filter resut to the same type object [Listfiles] instead datagrid,

When I am doing this:

```
Listfiles = Listfiles.Where(i => i.Status == FileStatus.NotProcessed).ToList();
```

it gives following erorr

> [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to
>   BindingList']

How can I convert generic list to `BindingList<FilesToProcessDataModels>`?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953461/convert-ilistt-to-bindinglistt

Answer (score 25, accepted):

below is the standard way - tho google should show this up easily -even on SO:

[Convert IList<T> to BindingList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953461/convert-ilistt-to-bindinglistt)

```
var listFiles= new List<FilesToProcessDataModels>();
var listBindingFiles = new BindingList<FilesToProcessDataModels>(listFiles);
```

Comment: Actually I am using derived class from BindingList. SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>. I just called two base constructor from derived class 1. 'public SortableBindingList(IList<T> collection) : base(collection){}' 2. 'public SortableBindingList() : base(){}'. Now it is working perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
var yourList = new List<FilesToProcessDataModels>();
var listBinding = new BindingList<FilesToProcessDataModels>(yourList);
```

Comment: @jimtollan Yeah, too bad Zeeshanef didn't take the 20 seconds to search for it on google (or SO) before creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Listfiles = Listfiles.Where(i => i.Status == FileStatus.NotProcessed).ToList();
```

I think you had defined ListFiles as BindingList<> bit now you are trying to assign a List<> to it.

That is the cause of that error