# BindingList vs List - WinForms Data Binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

In order to get data binding in WinForms (to a DataGridView, for instance) to work anything like you'd hope and add/delete rows as the collection changes, you have to use a BindingList (or DataTable) instead of a generic List.  The problem is, almost nobody has the first instinct to code with a BindingList instead of a List in their libraries.

The BindingList implements two events that the List doesn't have and these must be the difference in data binding action (also, a property to suppress the second event):

```
AddingNew
ListChanged
RaiseListChangedEvents
```

Similarly, the DataTable has two events which probably enable similar functionality:

```
RowDeleted
TableNewRow
```

**EDIT**: As the helpful SO community pointed out here [and in another article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398832/convert-generic-list-to-bindinglistt), a List can be converted (maybe more accurately encapsulated?) by calling the correct BindingList constructor:

```
BindingList<MyType> MyBL = new BindingList<MyType>();
MyList.ForEach(x => MyBL.Add(x));
```

My situation is a little more complicated as illustrated by the code below.
**EDIT** Added INotifyPropertyChanged stuff that must exist in the real library.

```
public class RealString : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private int _KnotCount = 0;
  private List<KnotSpace> _KnotSpacings = new List<KnotSpace>();

  public RealString()
  {
    KnotSpacings.Add(new KnotSpace());
  }

  public int KnotCount
  {
    get { return _KnotCount; }

    set
    {
      int requiredSpacings = 0;

      _KnotCount = value;
      // Always one more space than knots
      requiredSpacings = _KnotCount + 1;

      if (requiredSpacings < KnotSpacings.Count)
      {
        while (requiredSpacings < KnotSpacings.Count)
        {
          KnotSpacings.Add(new KnotSpace());
        }
      }
      else if (requiredSpacings > KnotSpacings.Count)
      {
        while (requiredSpacings > KnotSpacings.Count)
        {
          KnotSpacings.Remove(KnotSpacings.Last());
        }
      }
      this.OnPropertyChanged(this, "KnotCount");
    }

  }

  public List<KnotSpace> KnotSpacings { get => _KnotSpacings; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, string PropertyName)
  {
    if (this.PropertyChanged == null) return;
    this.PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
  }

}

public class KnotSpace
{
  private double _Spacing = 10;

  public double Spacing { get => _Spacing; set => _Spacing = value; }

}
```

The things in the list are displayed in the UI, and the properties of the things in the list are modified in the UI, but the UI doesn't directly add/remove things from the list except by changing the KnotCount property.  Wrapping the KnotSpacings property in a BindingList doesn't result in the BindingList updating when KnotSpacings is updated by changing the KnotCount property.

**EDIT** OK, more clarification...

```
BindingList BL = new BindingList<KnotSpace>(MyRealString.KnotSpacings);

DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataGridView1.DataSource = BL;
NumericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", MyRealString, "KnotCount", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

The BindingList has no more success tracking the changes to the underlying List property (KnotSpacings) than the Windows controls.  So data binding the controls to the BindingList doesn't accomplish much.  BindingList works great if UI adds/removes items from the BindingList because it does the same operations in the underlying List.  But then I would need to replicate the add/remove action and logic of the library in my UI and that's a breaking change in waiting.

**EDIT** Major changes made to my original post attempting to: (1) Clarify the problem. (2) Distinguish it as not a duplicate question (although one of the several questions was a dup). (3) Acknowledge the helpful efforts of others that would be lost if I deleted the post.

Comment: If you check the [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_BindingList_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IList__0__) docs, you find the ctor for the BindingList<T> that accepts an instance of IList<T>.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert generic list to BindingList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398832/convert-generic-list-to-bindinglistt)

Comment: You forgot the [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) class (which implements `IBindingListView`, among the others). You can use it to manage your List with a single command. Then, a `List<of what>`? If you have a `List<class>`, your class object then implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It doesn't? Well, it's not explicitly designed for data binding. But you can use a BindingSource anyway.

Comment: In a layered architecture, two-way data-binding is UI Layer's responsibility and it's not Business Logic Layer's or Service Layer's concern to care about it. If you want to have two-way data-binding you need to handle it in the UI layer by using model classes which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and lists which implement `IBindingList`.

Comment: Did you ever have a feeling you wasted a valuable piece of your life that you'll never get back?  If I had only slowed down and let IntelliSense do it's job I would have had an easy solution to my problem yesterday.  Thanks, @MarkBenningfield - if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: If your question is how to convert a List to BindingList, then please just keep the first question in the post and remove rest. The post in the current format is supposed to receive answers to rest of your questions about two-way data-binding.

Comment: Although I appreciate the code example, it's not exactly clear what isn't working here. Could you show us what you are attempting to bind to (both sides of the binding), and how you're currently trying to bind it? Also, there's no indication as to what exactly isn't working - maybe that answer comes with the answer to my last question but, if it doesn't, that information is going to be important.

Answer (score 2):

First Off, there is a better way to pass a `List<T>` to a `BindingList<T>`. `BindingList<T>` has a constructor that accepts a `List<T>` which copies the `List`'s elements into the `BindingList`, like so:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
BindingList<int> myBindingList = new BindingList<int>(myList);
```

But that's not your question, really. To answer your question simply - **Correct, `List<T>` is not a good choice for *two-way* binding in WinForms**. As `List<T>` does not have any events notifying for elements added, you can really only guarantee a one-way binding - data entry may work, but things break down when trying to refresh on, say, items being added to the `List`.

That said, you mention that these libraries are modifying a `List<T>` that you have access to during the modifications. I would argue that a good Library would use the Interface pattern to use, modify, and pass collections. Although `List<T>` and `BindingList<T>` are very different classes, they both implement `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, and `IEnumerable<T>`. So any function which accepts any of those interfaces as a parameter would accept either a `List<T>` or a `BindingList<T>` (for example: `public void DoSomethingWithCollection(IEnumerable<int> collection)` could accept `List<int>`, `BindingList<int>`, or any other collection that implements `IEnumerable<int>`). The Interface pattern is a well-known standard at this point in C#'s lifespan, and though nobody's first instinct would be to use a `BindingList<T>` over a `List<T>`, their first instinct should absolutely be to use an `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`) over a `List<T>`.

Where possible, it would be better for binding to pass your `List` to the `BindingList`'s constructor, then never use the `List` again - instead, use the `Add` and `Remove` methods of the `BindingList` to manage it's internal collection.

Comment: This is the answer, but @MarkBenningfield got to it first in his comment.  If he posts the comment as an answer, I'll accept his.  Otherwise, I'll accept yours. So many hours wasted, on such a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `BindingList<T>` constructor that accepts an instance of `IList<T>`, then that instance is used to back the `BindingList<T>`, and changes in the `IList<T>` are reflected in the `BindingList`.

That's not the end of the story, however. WinForms databinding is structured in such a way that, the further away you get from simple, single-property 2-way binding, the more things you have to cover yourself.

For example, the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is implemented by classes that are used as a data source to notify of a change in a child property (like your `KnotCount` property).

For more complex scenarios, one would not use `BindingList<T>`, but would derive a class from it and override one or more of the data binding mechanisms. Ditto for the `BindingSource` class.

There is a *lot* of boilerplate behind the data binding mechanism, but almost every portion of it is open to derivation in order to customize the behavior. It is sometimes useful to draw out an object graph of the classes and interfaces used in data binding (lots of reading the documentation involved) to give yourself a good mental overview of the whole process.

Comment: "changes in the IList<T> are reflected in the BindingList" I'm not finding this to be true, unfortunately.  As my example shows, the List inside the library is used to construct the BindingList via the library property exposing it.  When the library's KnotCount property changes its internal List, the BindingList doesn't update.  But changes to the BindingList definitely get propagated to the library's List.  Maybe if I could find a way to tell the BindingList to re-read the List?

Comment: The library presumably is responsible for supplying a list. If you want to use the list as a *data source*, then you need to use that list as a basis for a class of your own that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.