# Cannot Convert IList To Binding List

Tags: c#, winforms, bindinglist

I am developing an application in which I convert an `Object` to an `IList`. I then want to convert it to a `BindingList`

Here is the code I am trying

```
IList data = spareEntity.getall() as IList;
var listBinding = new BindingList<IList>(data);

public object getall()
{
    using (var worldbankAMSentitiesNew = new WorldBankAMSEntities())
    {
        var q = from fullSpareInventory in worldbankAMSentitiesNew.Spare_Inventory
        select new
        {
            fullSpareInventory.Is_Spare,
            fullSpareInventory.Manufacturer,
            fullSpareInventory.Product_No,
            fullSpareInventory.Remarks,
            fullSpareInventory.Remedy_Ticket_No,
            fullSpareInventory.Serial_No,
            fullSpareInventory.Spare_Type,
            fullSpareInventory.Spare_Inventory_Volume.Spare_Name,
            fullSpareInventory.Spare_ID,
            fullSpareInventory.Assigned_Date,
            fullSpareInventory.Description,
            fullSpareInventory.Spare_Volume_ID
        };
        return q.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am relatively New to Winform So please Explain Where I am going Wrong

Comment: What is the type of the element returned by `getall` method?

Comment: get all return object

Comment: what type of list it is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert IList<T> to BindingList<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953461/convert-ilistt-to-bindinglistt)

Comment: Is your intention to return an anonymous type or is that a mistake? Can you use types instead, i.e. `select new Inventory{ ... };` and change the returnvalue to `IList<Inventory>`? You wouldn't need the cast to IList and you could create a `BindingList<Inventory>` and use properties via intellisense (`Inventory` here is just a placeholder name)

Comment: Actually this is a case of join . I am getting values from 2 Tables and mapping them i can return them as object only

Comment: What do you mean by "can return them as object only"? Why can't you create a new class that holds this data?

Comment: Its already in a new common class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try as below :-

```
var yourList = spareEntity.getall() as List<Object>;
var listBinding = new BindingList<Object>(yourList);
```

Comment: Invalid Expression Term

Comment: it would be nice if you put full exception or the exact place where ur getting error @user3859356

Comment: should probably be `as List<Object>;` (i.e. no paranthesis)

Comment: @Default is correct, because you are using the 'as' syntax, parenthesis cannot be used.

Comment: yes updated ans @user3859356 remove parenthesis its typo and try again

Comment: Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Spare_ID' and no extension method 'Spare_ID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: make your method return type as List<object> instead of object @user3859356

Comment: Did that too


Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'

Comment: what I would suggest you to create one model class containing all the properties you selected and bind it as select new ClassName() {} and then return List<ClassName> and furthure on its good practise @user3859356

Answer (score 1):

```
new BindingList<IList>(data);
```

I think the IList type here is the error. Use the generic type that is usede by IList data .. Spare ? or something ...

Try object

```
new BindingList<object>(data);
```

Change your getall()

```
public IList<object> getall()
```

and

```
var data = spareEntity.getall();
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<object>.BindingList(System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: On q.toList

Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: it gives this error

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: i think that is not possible on the casting way while you are using anonymous types

Comment: yes but you cannot cast anonymous type to object ... thats the problem